# 16.04 System Settings not displaying

Tags: 16.04, unity-control-center

Clean installed 16.04.  Previously running 14.04 mostly without problems.
Box is an HP Z420 with a non-std display adapter (AMD Radeon R7 240).
Lone Ubuntu only (no other OSes).

Problem: System Settings won't display its GUI, whether launched from launcher or command line.  The unity-control-center process is running, but no GUI appears.  No terminal output either if launched from command line.

I've tried `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and `apt-get install --reinstall unity-control-center`.  Made no difference.

Looking for things to try or options for debugging or gathering a trace that might point out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I figure it out less than 24hrs after posting.

I found that `lsusb` was hanging.  I had a DELL S2340T monitor plugged into one of the USB3 ports (the monitor is a hub and also supports touch via USB...DisplayLink, etc.).  Unplugging that fixed `lsusb`, allowed `unity-control-center` to display, and also fixed a hang-at-logout problem.

No idea whether the problem is specific to the USB3 on this box or the just the monitor.  Don't care either, as I don't need any of the features of USB3 or USB from the monitor.  Just glad 16.04 is working now...